# Omissions of "that" in a relative clause

Tags: relative-clauses, relative-pronouns, omissibility

I am not clear on when the word "that" can be omitted in a relative clause.
I only know that when the modified noun is the object in the clause, the antecedent "that" can be omitted. Are there any other such situations?
How about the following sentence:

> Students should be skeptical about everything they are told.

I am not sure whether everything is the object, and if not, whether this sentence is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are the students told? - everything (well probably not absolutely everything!) - so *everything* is the object, and the sentence is fine.

Let's have the long version: 
*Students should be skeptical about everything **that** they are told*.
The fact that there's a pronoun (*they*) in subject form between the relative pronoun (*that*) and the verb, tells us that *they* is the subject. That's one easy way of deciding. What is probably throwing you is that the relative clause is in the passive, so it looks a bit strange. But just look for that pronoun.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I forgot that some sentences can have two objects. Then "everything (that)" is the direct object, the indirect object (students) in the active voice becomes the subject. (Active voice: [someone] tells the students something. I hope I'm right.) Yeah, it's a little complicated. Then my question title is not pertinent...

Comment: @LLS: Your analysis is right. Note that you can also leave out "that" if it is the object to a preposition that comes at the end of the relative clause: the woman I told you about. Note that "that" can also be left out if it is a conjunction: I told you he was mad.