# Use of the phrase "it seems" vs. "it seems that"

Tags: subordinate-clauses, omissibility, the-that

On another stackexchange site, I used the following phrasing:

> I want to do X.  It seems I can only do so when Y.

Someone edited the second sentence:

> It seems `that` I can only do so when Y.

This made me realise that the edited form is perhaps more common -- but is my original phrasing grammatically incorrect?  What role does "that" play in the second variation?

Comment: This has less to do with the phrase *it seems* than with the omission of *that* in general. Look up "omission of that" in Google Search. e.g., http://books.google.co.in/books?id=8v_SS6_9S34C&pg=PA321&lpg=PA321&dq=%22omission+of+that%22+grammar&source=bl&ots=bHvaXKQTAg&sig=G6iySDcG1_HqJ0TZ95Q1DE7V_zw&hl=en&sa=X&ei=DNSUUZrkPIiIrQeUm4HwDw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22omission%20of%20that%22%20grammar&f=false  -- http://www.englishforums.com/English/OmissionSubordinateConjunction/bhzhh/post.htm

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/8145/14666

Comment: Ok, I now understand my real question better.  But neither the other answer nor any of my google results explain the rules in terms I can understand.  :(

Comment: @starwed But perhaps you can rephrase the question now that you understand the issue better?

Comment: Also @TrevorD This question is better asked on ELL it seems.

Comment: @Kris OK. I haven't been here long enough to grasp what's acceptable on this board and what isn't, so I'm currently leaving that for others to comment on even if I have wondered about it.

Comment: @TrevorD The recently launched English Language Learners Q&A is a sister site. With ELU dealing with the more advanced grammar and usage questions, simpler questions are now referred to ell.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Kris  Yes, thanks. I knew of it, and have responded on it. As a newbie, I'm just hesitating on making judgments on which questions should be on which boards. Thanks for the guidance.

Comment: @Kris ELL is explicitly for "speakers of other languages learning English".   I'm a native speaker.  When I said I didn't understand the terms used, I meant jargon like "appositive clause".

Comment: @starwed  If there were a bit more info in your profile, answerers might know whether they're responding to a native speaker or learner.  As regards the question, I'm sorry I don't have an answer of whether one is grammatically wrong. Personally, I find the second version slightly easier to *read* - and, if *writing* it, I would use the latter (with *that*): I can't say whether I would prefer one or the other when *hearing* it. But I can't give more than a subjective view I'm afraid.

Comment: BTW, _seem_ is not the only predicate that takes a _that_-complement, though it does have extremely strange syntax. The _it_ part of "it seems" is a dummy created by extraposition, for instance. _Seem_ requires extraposition with a _that_-complement, and [A-Raising](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/cliffs-equi-raising.pdf) with an infinitive complement. These are normally optional rules, but _seem_ is an odd verb, as I say.

Comment: [“This is another example of *that*-complementizer. It's optional, and is often deleted; but since deleting stuff loses information, putting it back in often clarifies matters.” — John Lawler Aug 6 '13 at 14:09](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/121648/i-think-know-vs-i-think-know-that#comment250253_121648)

Answer (score 2):

One use of the word `that` is as a `complementizer`, a part of speech that is a type of `subordinating conjunction` in traditional grammars.  Complementizers introduce `complement clauses`, which are sentential clauses that may or may not stand alone and are the argument of the main verb:

- I believe *that* she is a good person.
- It seems *that* he can  perform miracles.

In other words, the clause `she is a good person` (which stands alone as a valid sentence), is the argument of the verb `believe`.  The argument of this use of `believe` is a complement clause, and so may optionally be introduced by the complementizer `that`.

When `that` is used as a complementizer, it is optional.  Omitting or including the `that` complementizer is a stylistic decision.  [Here](http://grammar.quickanddirtytips.com/omitting-that.aspx) is a good article that can help elucidate the factors that go into the decision (also available as a podcast at the same link).

Comment: Yes. A _That_-Complement is one of the [four types of English Complement Clauses](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/complementtypes.pdf). The _that_ is required only when the clause begins the sentence, where it's needed to mark a detour to a subordinate clause for the parser. _That he was late is unfortunate_ vs _*He was late is unfortunate._