# I think/know vs. I think/know that

Tags: subordinate-clauses, omissibility, the-that

I wonder when verbs like *think* or *know* are followed by *that*; I encountered both forms, is there a difference?

For example,

> I know that he did it. // I know he did it.

Are the two sentences both correct?

Comment: This is another example of _that_-complementizer. It's optional, and is often deleted; but since deleting stuff loses information, putting it back in often clarifies matters.

Comment: It is always advisable to wait for a day or two before "accepting" an answer, so more people get to see the question and, perhaps, offer their answers.

Comment: [“This is another example of *that*-complementizer. It's optional, and is often deleted; but since deleting stuff loses information, putting it back in often clarifies matters.” — John Lawler Aug 6 '13 at 14:09](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/121648/i-think-know-vs-i-think-know-that#comment250253_121648)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are both correct. I'd use the second because that's more idiomatic and shorter than the first one. There are times when you don't need "that" in a sentence and this seems to be one of those instances.