# "that" omission, subject-verb distance

Tags: relative-clauses, subordinate-clauses, omissibility, whiz-deletion

when can we remove 'that'? I've heard different opinions

I bought the book that is required for this course
I bought the book required for this course

I recommend that you take my advice
I recommend you take my advice

I know that you are correct
I know you are correct

the report that was approved by the board was written by Susan
the report approved by the board was written by Susan

We are studying advertisement strategies that other companies use to recruit minorities
We are studying advertisement strategies used by other companies to recruit minorities

Comment: yes, thanks Susan. I made a typo in the 4th pair.
What is the rule with keeping/removing 'that'? I heard that we should keep 'that' with thinking verbs like 'believe,' 'know,' 'realise' - true?

Comment: [“This is another example of *that*-complementizer. It's optional, and is often deleted; but since deleting stuff loses information, putting it back in often clarifies matters.” — John Lawler Aug 6 '13 at 14:09](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/121648/i-think-know-vs-i-think-know-that#comment250253_121648)

Answer (score 8):

If you want to know when you can omit *that* it is essential that you first understand the different functions of the word. In your examples, the *that* in the following sentences introduces an object clause:

> I recommend that you take my advice.
>
> I know that you are correct.

Similar examples are:

> I hope that you have a happy Christmas.
>
> I understand that you meant well.

In your other sentences the *that* introduces a relative clause (and could be replaced by '*which*' in each case). Your examples:

> I bought the book that (which) is required for this course.
>
> The report that (which) was approved by the board was written by
>   Susan.
>
> We are studying advertisement strategies that (which) other companies
>   use to recruit minorities.

Having clarified this fundamental difference in the function of *that*, we can now address the question of when *that* can be omitted. In the case of *that* introducing an object clause, in most cases it can be omitted - as it can be in your two example sentences. Note, however, that we do not usually omit *that* after intransitive verbs:

> ?He emailed he had sent the money.
>
> ?She whispered she was not feeling very well.

We also do not usually omit *that* after nouns:

> ?I don't believe his claim he was sick.
>
> ?Do you agree with the view what he did was wrong.

Turning to the second function of *that* (introducing a relative clause), whether it can be omitted depends on whether *that* is the subject or object of the clause. If it is the subject it cannot be omitted (but see below for passive constructions). If it is the object, it can.

> Subject: Philatelists are people that collect stamps.
>
> Object:  Show me the stamps (that) you bought last week.
>
> Object:  We are studying advertisement strategies (that) other
>   companies use to recruit minorities.

Finally, note that in your other two relative clause sentences, you cannot omit just the *that* but must also omit the finite verb:

> I bought the book (that is) required for this course.
>
> The report (that was) approved by the board was written by Susan.

What we have here is a passive construction which permits such elision.

Comment: I prefer your answer, Shoe, but feel [that] there's enough non-overlap to leave mine too.

Comment: How about this then; Is this an object clause (so omit that)? Is told an intransitive verb (so keep that)?
I was told that you are an experienced accountant

Comment: This is my take, can you guys verify this:  
OMIT THAT - when there is 2 entities e.g.  
"I" was told "you" are an experienced accountant.  
"I" just knew "it" was something I wanted to do.  
"I" realised "you" were right all along"

KEEP THAT when there is ONE entity (same person):
"I" realised that "I" was right all along
"he" emailed that "he" had sent the money

Comment: Last one: The attorney believed that her client was guilty

Comment: @Student. _Tell_ is a transitive verb, hence it is permissible to omit _that_: _I was told (that) you are an experienced accountant_. The omission of _that_ has nothing to do with the subject of the _that-clause_, as you hypothesise. It has to do with the transitivity of the verb (in its context). _Realize_ is a transitive verb so both _I realised I was right all along_ and _I realised that I was right all along_ are permissible. _Want_ and _believe_ are also transitive, whereas _email_ in its context here is intransitive.

Comment: @Shoe I'm sorry, but what do you mean by transitive and intransitive; because *email* is a transitive verb at least according to my dictionaries, i.e. Longman and Cambridge.

Comment: *She whispered she was not feeling very well.* Wouldn't we more usually say *She whispered **that** she was not feeling very well.**

Answer (score 4):

Notice that you give different types of construction in your examples.

In **the book that is required** etc *that* is a relative pronoun (= French *lequel*).

In **recommend that you take** etc *that* is a subordinator (= French *que*).

[Wikipedia comments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced_relative_clause):

> Because of the omission of function words, the use of reduced relative
>   clauses, particularly when nested, can give rise to sentences which,
>   while theoretically correct grammatically, are not readily parsed by
>   listeners.
>
> . . . Reduced relative clauses often give rise to ambiguity or garden
>   path effects, and have been a common topic of psycholinguistic study,
>   especially in the field of sentence processing.

............
Examples of dodgy omissions are:

> The horse raced past the barn fell down.

(relative pronoun and form of be omitted - whiz deletion)

> I know those gentlemen with the very large noses like carrots.

(subordinator omitted)

Comment: Perhaps" the horse raced past the "fallen" barn.

Comment: @Student I think you got it  wrong. Here is my take: 1- The horse **that** raced past the barn fell. 2- The horse raced past the barn **that** fell.